# Change text of element for each element that have the same class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm trying to only show certain part of the text. The info is passed like this. Ex: ["PS4"] and I only want the PS4 text to show so I did this with jQuery:

```
var text = $('.gender').text();
var text2=text.substring(text.indexOf('"')+1,text.lastIndexOf('"'));
$('.gender').text(text2);
```

The problem is that I want to change every single element text that have .gender class but only having their corresponding text, like so:

["PS4"]["XBOX"]

```
<div class="gender">PS4</div><div class="gender">XBOX</div>
```

I tried to do it with .each() function but I got something like this:

```
<div class="gender">PS4"]["XBOX</div><div class="gender">PS4"]["XBOX</div>
```

Here's the code with jQuery .each():

```
$('.gender').each(function(){
    var text = $('.gender').text();
    var text2=text.substring(text.indexOf('"')+1,text.lastIndexOf('"'));
    $('.gender').text(text2);
});
```

EDIT:

I have an HTML with this:

```
<div class="gender">["PS4"]</div>
<div class="gender">["XBOX"]</div>
```

So I want to remove the '[""]' from every element that have `.gender` class so it shows like this:

```
<div class="gender">PS4</div>
<div class="gender">XBOX</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're attempting to do. Could you edit the question to show what the HTML looks like by default, and what you want it to look like after the jQuery has been executed on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)` and not `$(".gender")`

```
$('.gender').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  var text2 = text.substring(text.indexOf('"') + 1, text.lastIndexOf('"'));
  $(this).text(text2);
});
```

**demo**

```js
$('.gender').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  var text2 = text.substring(text.indexOf('"') + 1, text.lastIndexOf('"'));
  $(this).text(text2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gender">["PS4"]</div>
<div class="gender">["XBOX"]</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working. I will accept your answer when it's available :)

Comment: @AlexanderArce No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You may go for `RegEx`, with `$.text(callback)`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.gender').text(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(/^\[\"(.*)\"\]$/, '$1');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gender">["PS4"]</div>
<div class="gender">["XBOX"]</div>
```

Breakup of, `^\[\"(.*)\"\]$` as below:

- `^` starts with
- `(.*)` group having any match of any length
- `$` ends with

Answer (score 0):

Try this one also:

```js
$('.gender').each(function() {
   var text = $(this).text();
   var text2 = text.replace("\"]", "");
   text2 = text2.replace("[\"", "");
   
  $(this).text(text2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gender">["PS4"]</div>
<div class="gender">["XBOX"]</div>
```